# How to save changes made to an array list in java

Tags: java

I am just a beginner in java coding and I want to know how I can save changes made to an array list through a GUI i have created. This code allows to store data, remove, add, update student information. However it is only temporarily since it is not connected to the hard disk to permanently store this information. I am wondering how I can make this code save the modified information made to it after i close it. I thank you for your time and consideration. The main class code is:

```
public class StudentDataStorage {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textStudentName;
    private JTextField textStudentId;
    private JTextField textCourseId;
    private JTextField textCourseSubject;

    void clearFields() {
        textStudentName.setText("");
        textStudentId.setText("");
        textCourseId.setText("");
        textCourseSubject.setText("");
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    StudentDataStorage window = new StudentDataStorage();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    private ArrayList<Student> arrayList;
    private ListIterator<Student> listIterator;
    int size;

    public StudentDataStorage() {
        initialize();
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        size = 0;
        arrayList.add(new Student("Jon Rugova", 340007862, "ISTE.121.500", "CompProblemSolvingInfoDomainII"));
        arrayList.add(new Student("Sindi Rryta", 125172286, "ACCT.210.501", "Management Accounting"));
        arrayList.add(new Student("Arianit Sylafeta", 545919686, "MTSC.231..501", "Contemporary Science: Biology"));
        arrayList.add(new Student("Enxo Muçaj", 223375558, "POLS.110.500", "American Politics"));
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 991, 656);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(6, 0, 979, 65);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Student Data Storage");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(287, 6, 393, 44);
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 36));
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBounds(6, 64, 979, 315);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblStudentName = new JLabel("Student Name");
        lblStudentName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblStudentName.setBounds(164, 57, 196, 23);
        lblStudentName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        panel_1.add(lblStudentName);

        textStudentName = new JTextField();
        textStudentName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        textStudentName.setBounds(372, 55, 421, 26);
        panel_1.add(textStudentName);
        textStudentName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblIdNumber = new JLabel("Student ID");
        lblIdNumber.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblIdNumber.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblIdNumber.setBounds(164, 101, 196, 23);
        panel_1.add(lblIdNumber);

        textStudentId = new JTextField();
        textStudentId.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        textStudentId.setColumns(10);
        textStudentId.setBounds(372, 99, 421, 26);
        panel_1.add(textStudentId);

        JLabel lblCourseId = new JLabel("Course ID");
        lblCourseId.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblCourseId.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblCourseId.setBounds(164, 145, 196, 23);
        panel_1.add(lblCourseId);

        textCourseId = new JTextField();
        textCourseId.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        textCourseId.setColumns(10);
        textCourseId.setBounds(372, 143, 421, 26);
        panel_1.add(textCourseId);

        JLabel lblCourseSubject = new JLabel("Course Subject");
        lblCourseSubject.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        lblCourseSubject.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblCourseSubject.setBounds(164, 186, 196, 23);
        panel_1.add(lblCourseSubject);

        textCourseSubject = new JTextField();
        textCourseSubject.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        textCourseSubject.setColumns(10);
        textCourseSubject.setBounds(372, 184, 421, 26);
        panel_1.add(textCourseSubject);

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_2.setBounds(6, 378, 979, 250);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel_2);
        panel_2.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnFirst = new JButton("First");
        btnFirst.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                size = arrayList.size();
                listIterator = arrayList.listIterator();
                Student ss;
                ss = listIterator.next();
                textStudentName.setText(ss.getName());
                textStudentId.setText(""+ss.getStudentId());
                textCourseId.setText(ss.getCourseId());
                textCourseSubject.setText(ss.getCourseSubject());

            }
        });                                        

        btnFirst.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnFirst.setBounds(151, 56, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnFirst);

        JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(textStudentName.getText().contentEquals("")||textStudentId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseSubject.getText().contentEquals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Some Fields Are Empty!");
                }else {
                    if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Student ss;
                        ss = listIterator.next();
                        textStudentName.setText(ss.getName());;
                        textStudentId.setText(""+ss.getStudentId());
                        textCourseId.setText(ss.getCourseId());
                        textCourseSubject.setText(ss.getCourseSubject());
                        }else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Have Reached the Last Student.");
                        }
                    }
                }
        });
        btnNext.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnNext.setBounds(317, 56, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnNext);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add Data");
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(textStudentName.getText().contentEquals("")||textStudentId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseSubject.getText().contentEquals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Some Fields Are Empty!");
                }else {
                    String name = textStudentName.getText();
                    int studentid = Integer.parseInt(textStudentId.getText());
                    String courseid = textCourseId.getText();
                    String coursesubject = textCourseSubject.getText();
                    arrayList.add(new Student(name, studentid, courseid, coursesubject));
                    size = arrayList.size();
                    clearFields();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Data Added Successfully!");
                }
            }
        });
        btnAdd.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnAdd.setBounds(483, 56, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnAdd);

        JButton btnRemove = new JButton("Remove");
        btnRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(textStudentName.getText().contentEquals("")||textStudentId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseSubject.getText().contentEquals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Some Fields Are Empty!");
                }else {
                    String name = textStudentName.getText();
                    int studentid = Integer.parseInt(textStudentId.getText());
                    String courseid = textCourseId.getText();
                    String coursesubject = textCourseSubject.getText();
                    for(Student s:arrayList) {
                        if(studentid == s.getStudentId()) {
                            arrayList.remove(s);
                            listIterator = arrayList.listIterator();
                            clearFields();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Data Removed Successfully!");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnRemove.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnRemove.setBounds(649, 56, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnRemove);

        JButton btnLast = new JButton("Last");
        btnLast.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                size = arrayList.size();
                listIterator = arrayList.listIterator(arrayList.size());
                    if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                        Student ss;
                        ss = listIterator.previous();
                        textStudentName.setText(ss.getName());;
                        textStudentId.setText(""+ss.getStudentId());
                        textCourseId.setText(ss.getCourseId());
                        textCourseSubject.setText(ss.getCourseSubject());
                    }
                }
        });
        btnLast.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnLast.setBounds(151, 144, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnLast);

        JButton btnPrevious = new JButton("Previous");
        btnPrevious.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(textStudentName.getText().contentEquals("")||textStudentId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseSubject.getText().contentEquals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Some Fields Are Empty!");
                }else {
                    if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                        Student ss;
                        ss = listIterator.previous();
                        textStudentName.setText(ss.getName());;
                        textStudentId.setText(""+ss.getStudentId());
                        textCourseId.setText(ss.getCourseId());
                        textCourseSubject.setText(ss.getCourseSubject());
                        }else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Have Reached the First Student.");
                        }
                    }
            }
        });
        btnPrevious.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnPrevious.setBounds(317, 144, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnPrevious);

        JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update Data");
        btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(textStudentName.getText().contentEquals("")||textStudentId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseId.getText().contentEquals("")||textCourseSubject.getText().contentEquals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Some Fields Are Empty!");
                }else {
                    String name = textStudentName.getText();
                    int studentid = Integer.parseInt(textStudentId.getText());
                    String courseid = textCourseId.getText();
                    String coursesubject = textCourseSubject.getText();
                    for(Student s:arrayList) {
                        if(studentid == s.getStudentId()) {
                            s.setName(name);
                            s.setCourseId(courseid);
                            s.setCourseSubject(coursesubject);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Changes Have Been Made Successfully!");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btnUpdate.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnUpdate.setBounds(483, 144, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnUpdate);

        JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnExit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnExit.setBounds(649, 144, 139, 68);
        panel_2.add(btnExit);
    }
}
```

-jon

Comment: Jon, you need to give more detail to your question, including the code and specific location in the code where your error/problem is. If not, the question will be closed as too vage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow Jon, please read [question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: You may want to look for and read tutorials on serialization and deserialization of Java objects like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/)

Comment: Please paste the actual java code into the question rather than trying to link out elsewhere.

Comment: I added the code now it should be more clearer. I thank you all for your replies.

Comment: You need a database to store the information. You can store the information in a [file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) as well but it will be difficult for you to work with the data stored in the file.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Aha I see. Thank you very much for your response. I just started a java course and I had a project to do with arraylists and guis. I am not sure how databases work since we haven't thoroughly gone through them. Anyway I think I'll just leave it that. :)